# How Create New Rest Api In My Module Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9

**I have a new module CRUD Banner Android**

[image]

**and New Database**

[image]

How create new Rest API in new My Module Magento ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It easy to create a new rest api in Magento 1.9.x but quite lengthy.Here I am posting the link instead answer please follow the link to get solution.
[Click Here](http://www.ipragmatech.com/customize-magento-rest-api/)